# How to keep two gestureRecognizers in one view and switch between them?

Tags: ios, swift, gesture

I am having trouble my UIPageViewController. What I ve done sofar:
1. On pageViewController you can swipe left, right in order to change VC
2. added lateral menu. When adding lateral menu, I created pangesture recognizer and added it to pageContentVC (so I can drag pageContentVC in order to close sidebar menu)

```
 var menuViewController: UIViewController! {
    didSet {
        self.exitPanGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer()
        self.exitPanGesture.addTarget(self, action:"handleOffstagePan:")
      //  self.exitPanGesture.view?.userInteractionEnabled = false
        self.sourceViewController.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.exitPanGesture)

    }
}
```

Here I am setting pageContentVC to sourceVC of transitionManager:

```
 func resetToMainPage(index: Int!) {
    /* Getting the page View controller */
    mainPageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainPageViewController") as UIPageViewController
    self.mainPageViewController.dataSource = self
    self.mainPageViewController.delegate = self

    let pageContentViewController = self.viewControllerAtIndex(index)

    self.transtionManger.sourceViewController = pageContentViewController // adding swipe to the pageContentViewControlle in order to close menu

    self.mainPageViewController.setViewControllers([pageContentViewController!], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)


    self.mainPageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 102, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height)
    self.addChildViewController(mainPageViewController)
    self.view.addSubview(mainPageViewController.view)
    self.mainPageViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

}
```

3. After closing menu I disabled pangesture recognizer.
   ` var presentingP:Bool!{
       didSet{
           if presentingP == true {
               // enable the gesture recognizer only when the view of menucontroller is presented

   ```
           self.exitPanGesture.view?.userInteractionEnabled = true
       }else{
           // disable gesture recognizer when menu is not presented
           self.exitPanGesture.view?.userInteractionEnabled = false

           isMenuVisible = false
       }
   }
   ```

   }
   ` Sofar, I can swipe left, and right in order to change VC. 
   The problem is that I can't scroll tableView on my VC. After I disabled pageContentVC gesture, everything become disable except swiping right and left (to change VC). Question: How to keep two gestureRecognizers in one view and switch between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `enabled` property of `UIGestureRecognizer` to disable the one you don't want to use and enable the other one.

[UIGestureRecognizer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIGestureRecognizer/enabled)

Comment: It works ! When I disable exitPanGesture! Is it possible instead of assigning PageContentViewController assign the PageviewController ? Why this doesnt work?